# generating c++ refactoring script

Tags: c++, refactoring, sed

I have to perform refactoring of a medium size code block (< 200K LOC). The scope is pretty moderate: rename some classes, move a few nested definitions up and down the class hierarchy, remove unused stuff.

It would be pretty straightforward to do it by hand but we will have to pick up bug fixes from the older code base for one or two years, and the project will change at least half of lines in the existing code.

So, I am planning to express the changes as a sequence of indent (supposedly astyle), sed script, and another indent.

My plans are: do conversion by hand, then develop the sed script that will yeld the same result. The former part is pretty clear, but developing bit sed script by hand does not seem particularly appealing but I do not have any better idea.

Please, help.

Comment: Parsing c++ is *hard*, which means that, unless the code in question is *very* regular, this is going to be a hard, hard problem.

Comment: Thanks for all responses. As a result I had chosen the easy way out: (1) properly isolate parts where we expect development activity from the core using abstract interface, (2) refactor the core, (3) attach isolated parts to new core, (4) maintain old code in buildable state and (5) do manual merges for bugfixes in the core and uninsulatged parts. As bonus we can do some refactoring insulated parts in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the large scale static analysis and refactoring tools that mozilla devs were working on

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Static_Analysis

I'm not sure what has happened since the release of gcc 4.5 - possibly pork and oink are easier to set up now.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` can probably be cozened into doing it, but for multiline blocks you're better off with something easier to work with.  Even `awk` would be an improvement, but I'd be looking at Perl/Python/scripting language of choice.  Preferably with a parser, which would also save you the initial `indent` run.

In fact, I'd look for a parser that generated an annotated syntax tree, which makes refactoring largely a matter of moving tree branches around.

Comment: What about brute force approach:

Comment: With `sed`, writing it's going to be *very* brutish.  Try writing a `sed` script to relocate a block of code.  Then use something sensible to do it.